# no "Perfomense" in sentry project on NestJs

Tags: nestjs, sentry

No data on the Performance tab in Sentry. The project is written in NestJS.
I connect Sentry like this

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: '*',
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    preflightContinue: true,
  });
  const config = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  const dsnSentry = config.get('SENTRY_DSN');
      Sentry.init({
        dsn: dsnSentry,
        environment: config.get('ENV'),
        integrations: [
          new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
        ],
        tracesSampleRate: 1,
      });
```

...

```
  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler());
```

How do I get Performance in Sentry? Right now it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/4731
some people had problems if this import was missing:

```
import "@sentry/tracing";
```

Comment: now this is no longer needed @sentry/tracing is deprecated